# TypeError: src data type = 23 is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, typing

hope you're all having a great day so far.

I have a python 3.6 script that applies random (well, in fact it's more like exhaustively all existing) sequences of image transformations with openCV to an image, compare it to a seeken result and try the next one.

Image transformations include:

- Thresholding
- Morphological transformation
- Smoothing
- Playing with colors (with cvtColor, but also hand-made algorithm)
- Playing with gradients

I won't show the code for this since it's basically just a heavy set of loops and arrays, which I think couldn't be linked to my issue.

Obviously enough most of the tried combinations aren't valid ones since, for example, converting BGR to GRAY might not work well if done after a conversion from BGR to GRAY. I know it's not very pythonic of me, since opposed to EAFP thinking, but since exception-catching cost a lot and happened pretty often, and sometime after some heavy treatment, I wanted to add a few conditions which would prevent most of them.

To do so, I sorted my array of functions and, by checking if I'm within a certain range, I can check the validity of the transformation to come and abort if bad.

```
if steps[it] >= THREE_CHANNELS_LIMIT:
    if len(cur_img.shape) == 3:
        if steps[it] >= SINGLE_CHANNEL_LIMIT:
            break
        elif cur_img.dtype not in BGR_DEPTHS:
            break
```

Where steps[it] is the index pointing to the next function to execute, and THREE_CHANNELS_LIMIT or SINGLE_CHANNEL_LIMIT are the specific index at the border of each function range. 
The above code prevents single-channel transformations to be done on multi-channel numpy image.

Now with my issue : from logged exceptions, I can see a few functions, the OpenCV morphological functions, are still throwing errors.
`TypeError: src data type = 23 is not supported`

Which I think is probably an issue with pixel depth. However, I have no idea what type 23 is/means, and I would like to know it in order to guess how often the issue occurs and determine whether or not I should add another condition or let the try-except statement deal with it.

Searched through the web but found many type = 17, type = 18 or type = 0 issues, but can't seem to find this one.

Is there a file somewhere listing all of OpenCV types used for Error message? Or maybe one of you know about this specific one, which would do the trick for my present case?

And sorry for my innacurate english. Current speelchecker just underline everything so I might have left many typos, too.

Comment: Also there's a lacking elif at the trail of my conditions so some of it might seem pretty pointless.
`elif steps[it] < SINGLE_CHANNEL_LIMIT:`
Also checking same condition in different blocks seems ugly, any better way to do that? Maybe something specific to python?

Comment: It is not possible to generate a `cv::Mat` of type 23 from the native data types. The only way of generating one is using `cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(100, 100, CV_BIG_INT(23));`. But I don't know How can a method return this data type. `CV_BIG_INT(23)` refers to Long Long 23 bit integer.

Comment: Oh well, then it would all make sense, I was using classes my boss did for this project and a few were making divide by 0 errors, which in python only raise a warning. 

Is it possible for those division to have created "really big numbers", thus "Long Long 23 bit integer" ? (Tho the 23 bit part means it wouldn't be so long, and an odd number... meh?)

Anyway, I think it helps... and I guess I can find the OpenCV type enum now that I know the 23 actually comes from there, will help alot for future errors. c:

Comment: @Zdar it's a 3 channel mat of [`CV_USRTYPE1`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L74) (16 + 7) -- `CV_MAKETYPE(CV_USRTYPE1,3)`. I see this used in [a few places](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=CV_USRTYPE1&type=), but so far I haven't got a clue of how it's supposed to work.

Comment: But there is no API for creating a 3-channel `CV_USERTYPE1` Mat, However one way could be generate 3 `Mat`s and then merging them.